# Why NULL values are not allowed in PriorityQueue ? (Java)

Tags: java, priority-queue

PriorityQueue doesn't allow null values to be stored in the queue. I want to know why ?

Comment: `null` is a [special return value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll--) indicating that the list is empty.

Answer (score 3):

`null` is a [special return value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#poll--) indicating that the list is empty.

The designers of the class wouldn't be able to use `null` for this purpose if it were a value you could otherwise insert into the queue.

Comment: Which is something it gets from [`Queue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html), which says *"Queue implementations generally do not allow insertion of null elements, although some implementations, such as LinkedList, do not prohibit insertion of null. Even in the implementations that permit it, null should not be inserted into a Queue, as null is also used as a special return value by the poll method to indicate that the queue contains no elements."* So even if an implementation allows `null`s, you shouldn't do that. (Nice API design. :-) )

Comment: Yeah, "nice" API design. You'd think they would have learned . . .

Answer (score 0):

Priority Queue uses Comparator to compare values. While comparing values we compare a data to a null value . For example . A object stored in priority queue has two members , int age and String name. You can compare any value of these. But if you given the object as null you cant compare between them and those two members. Thats why they throw a null pointer exception. If there is no null pointer exception , there will be another exception thrown while comparing the values.